# Clang format: space before comma?

Tags: clang-format

Is there a way to configure clang-format to put a space before a comma?
(don't judge that formatting style)

```
int func( int paramA, int paramB, int paramC )
                    v            v
int func( int paramA , int paramB , int paramC )
```

The same goes for a space before the semicolon in a (not necessarily empty) `for( ; ; )`-loop, initializer lists for array's etc., pretty much everywhere in front of a comma/semicolon.
I've already looked through the [docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) without much success.

Is there a way with clang-format to do this?

Comment: No this isn't supported at present, you could submit a patch but it's a rare style I've never come across before so do check first that the clang team would actually accept it!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option to do that and there aren't any plans to create one.